# Converting 'Time.now' to UTC without changing the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have this line in my `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```

It's hard to remain consistent with UTC and -0500. If I provide `11:40` in a rails form, and save it to the database, it saves in UTC as `2000-01-01 23:40:00`. However, `Time.now` shows as follows:

```
Time.now
# => 2018-10-08 23:45:58 -0500
```

Is there any way to have `Time.now` converted to UTC as well? I just want to drop `-0500` from the time so that the new time becomes `23:45:58 UTC`. Is this possible?

I tried `Time.now.utc`, but this changes the time (from `23:45:58` to `4:46am`):

```
Time.now.utc
# => 2018-10-09 04:46:08 UTC
```

Comment: Incase you mentioned `default_timezone = :utc` to use it You need to use `.zone`  eg: - `Time.zone.now`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved with:

```
Time.zone.local_to_utc(Time.now)
```

Comment: You should use `Time.current` inside a rails application

Comment: Didn't even realize this was a thing. Thanks for the suggestion.